# What is the iOS equivalent of Android's startActivityForResult/setResult?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am an Android programmer learning iOS. I have a swift view1 that calls an objective C view2. I am looking to return a String from view2 back to view 1.

In Android, we would simply view1.startActivityForResult(View2.class)

What is the iOS way to do this?

Comment: How is this different from your previous question (which you accepted an answer for)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ViewController2.h - Objective-C

```
@protocol ViewController2Delegate <NSObject>
- (void)sendStringBack:(NSString *)aString;
@end 

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ViewController2Delegate> delegate;
@end
```

ViewController2.m - Objective-C

```
// When you want to send the string back and dismiss the view:
[self.delegate sendStringBack:theStringToSendBack];
```

ViewController1.swift - Swift

```
@objc class ViewController1: UIViewController, ViewController2Delegate {
     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let viewContr = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
        viewContr.delegate = self
    }

    func sendStringBack(aString: String) {
        let aVariable = aString
        // do something with the string

        // dismiss the view if you presented it modally
        self.dismissViewController(self, animated: true, completion: nil)

        // OR
        // dismiss the view if you presented it with show/push
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, great answer, but could you please elaborate a bit more? Is there any action I have to take on the ViewController1? Do I have to create the sendStringBack method?

Comment: On ViewController1, you have to declare that you conform to ViewController2Delegate (which is in the @objc class... line). Once the compiler knows you conform to ViewController2Delegate, it will tell you to implement sendStringBack(). sendStringBack should autocomplete for you using intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like startActvityForResult() in iOS. You have to do it manually. I did it with the following process.
ViewControllerOne has a form that needed data from viewControllerTwo. ViewControllerTwo has a tableView with dataList. By tapping a data on the tableView of ViewControllerTwo it will go back to ViewControllerOne with the table data that was tapped.

1. Create a global variable for storing data.
       var data:String = ""
2. Open ViewControllerTwo from ViewControllerOne with segue.
3. In ViewControllerTwo which has a tablewView. In didSelectRowAt method set the data to global variable and Call the method 
   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) like below.

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       data = dataList[indexPath.row]
       self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
   }
4. It will go back to ViewControllerOne. Now You have catch the  data in viewWillAppear() or viewDidAppear() method. For example:

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       if data != ""{
           // Do whatever you want with this data. after doing your work set the data value to empty.
           data = ""
       }
   }

**Thats it. Happy Coding. It will work 100% sure**

Answer (score -1):

Use [UIViewController+CallBack](https://github.com/ods2-hamid/UIViewController-CallBack) for this purpose.

Only need to set the resulting object from parent controller and child controller will override the protocol method and return any kind of object to the parent.

> - (id)viewUnloadWithResultObject

No ned to set the protocol

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];
    [controller setResultBlock:^(id resultObject) {
        NSLog(@"New View Controller did pop and resulting object is: %@", resultObject);
    }];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

You can also present the view controller and get same resulting object

```
UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];
    [controller setResultBlock:^(id resultObject) {
        NSLog(@"New View Controller did dismissed and resulting object is: %@", resultObject);
    }];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Also you can have view unload call back methods. i.e.

> - (void)viewWillUnloadCallBack
> - (void)viewDidUnloadCallBack

Just inherit protocol and override these methods in your view controller to get the unload call backs.